# How to catch client side errors

Tags: html, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I have angular2 project, how can I catch errors on client side, error 'Failed to load'. I want to control situation if some of html files doesn't exists my page wouldn't fail, but I'll get exception in console.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to handle exception, so you can done it in typescript using try catch and finally block. typescript allow us to use try catch.
A reference for **Try Catch**
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/try-catch-statement-in-typescript/

If you need in html, then you need to handle as case in html using some variables

Comment: Which ng event I should use for it? and should I do this in each component typescript file? thanks

Comment: I prefer you should handle in this in each component typescript file.
I upto you whether you use in each component typescript file or use generic somewhere in you project